# Re-render only set of UI elements of the screen in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I'm writing a reat-native app which contains a set of text boxes, section list and a popup dialog (react-native-popup). In every 15 second I'm fetching the data from the remote server using a timer and updates data in the section list. Due to the state change the app re-renders the whole screen. Is there anyway that I can render only the section list and keep other UI elements as it is (stop popup being dismissed by the render) without re-rendering them in every 15 seconds?

Comment: Why don't you move your forms (component that you want to re-render) into separate component and fetch data their? You can also use [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) to restrict your component to re-render. Use [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) for state management.

Comment: I'm using redux for state management. Those are separate components used in one component to provide the specific output

Comment: Here is `React` [Static Component](https://github.com/reactjs/react-static-container), I don't know it will work with react native and your case or not.

Comment: Why you are using static container in your app ? Perhaps without using static container your app will work as you want.